# C# WPF. Как остановить отрисовку элемента

Tags: c#, wpf

Возникла такая проблема. Есть TreeView который отрисовывает дерево элементов:

```
public class Item
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }

    }
```

В xaml-разметке все выглядит так:

```
<TreeView Name="PRT" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, IsAsync=True}" />
                </Border>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Если записать много элементов то прорисовка каждого элемента занимает много времени. Собственно проблема в том что DataContext TreeView может переключаться на другой список элементов, но так как текущий не успел прорисоваться то происходит продолжение отрисовки старого списка, но в DataContext уже находится другой список. Подскажите как можно остановить обработку отрисовки и потом ее возобнавить.

Comment: А если скрыть элемент, а потом снова показать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545942/how-can-i-handle-layoutupdated-or-stop-a-control-rendring-in-wpf

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Скрыть/показать не получится так как одновременно нужно работать только с одним списком элементов. Пост выше видел, пробовал не подходид

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545942/how-can-i-handle-layoutupdated-or-stop-a-control-rendring-in-wpf) представлена сборка из способов прекратить отрисовку:

1. Если у `Visibility` поставить значение `Collapsed`, то элемент пропустит логику отрисовки
2. Можно приостановить работу отрисовки всего UI через [`Dispatcher.DisableProcessing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.disableprocessing.aspx)

   ```
   using (Dispatcher.DisableProcessing())
   {
   // Do work while the dispatcher processing is disabled.
   }
   ```
3. Можно удалить элемент целиком, а потом добавить новый.

Я бы на вашем месте попробовал бы еще включить виртуализацию, ведь скорее всего вы большую часть элементов не видите на экране=> отрисуется штук 10, а остальные будут рисовать по мере прокрутки => вам не придется ждать всей отрисовки.

```
        <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Dispatcher.DisableProcessing() пробовал такой вариант. Он останавливает работу всего application

Comment: А виртуализацию пробовали? Ведь скорее всего вы не видите за раз все элементы => их можно не рисовать.

Comment: Нет, отображаются все элементы. Я слишком утрировано описал реализацию, по факту каждый TreeViewItem привязывается к свойствам объекта.

Comment: подробно рассмотрев код, понял что весь процесс отрисовки тормозят прикрепленные свойства зависимостей (DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached). Как понял именно привязка через них удерживает старый список и пака в установленном порядке не прорисует - не отпускает